# Related Rates - Finding dx/dt

Tags: calculus

I've attempted this problem 11 times now using veriest resources and I can't get it. Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:

```
Suppose that x = x(t) and y = y(t) are both functions of t. If 

     y^2 + xy -3x = 5

and dy/dt = 1 when x = -1 and y = -1, what is dx/dt?
```

I'm trying to start by converting the above into this:

```
2y + x (dx/dy) * y (dy/dt) - 3 = 0
```

but it never comes out to the correct answer once I plug in the values so now i'm completely lost.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since x and y are both functions of t, how did you apply your chainrule?

Comment: I'm not sure since I'm a bit lost with this one.

Comment: Derivative of $y^2$ is not $2y$, rather $2y*y'$ with $y'$ being $dy/dt$.

Comment: The derivative of $y^2$ with respect to $t$ is $2y\frac{dy}{dt}$. The derivative of $xy$ with respect to $t$ is $x\frac{dy}{dt}+y\frac{dx}{dt}$. The derivative of $-3x$ with respect to $t$ is $-3\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation $y^2+xy-3x=5$ becomes, after differentiation using the chain rule and the product rule,

$$2y\frac{dy}{dt}+y\frac{dx}{dt}+x\frac{dy}{dt}-3\frac{dx}{dt}=0$$

Can you continue from there?

Comment: I'm attempting it now.

Comment: Ah, yes I got the correct answer from this. My initial step was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

By taking the derivative of $y^2 + xy -3x = 5$ with respect to $t$, we  get
$$2y\frac{dy}{dt}+x\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{dx}{dt}y-3\frac{dx}{dt}=0.$$
By substitution,
$$-2-1-\frac{dx}{dt}-3\frac{dx}{dt}=0,$$
implying that
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac34\cdot$$

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't $\frac{d}{dt} (y^2 +xy - 3x = 5) \Rightarrow 2y\frac{dy}{dt} + y\frac{dx}{dt} + x\frac{dy}{dt} - 3\frac{dx}{dt}  $
??

Comment: Yeah, that's the part I didn't have correct which kept giving me the incorrect answer.